# jQuery execute code each time element has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to execute a piece of code each time a specific element has a certain class in jQuery.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the code only executes once, then seems unactive. I'm using an if statement, but I also tried while. When I tried while the nothing really worked so that wasn't a good idea. Is there any solution? Here's the code:

```
if($(".slide:first").hasClass("active-slide")) {
    $(".prev").hide();
    $(".next").click (function () {
        $(".prev").show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is that code being called from?

Comment: can we see the html that goes with it, also how is this to be triggered ? maybe you could make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's called as soon as the DOM is loaded. The html is a section with some divs in it. The divs have the class "slide". Under the section are two links with the classes "prev" and "next"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery queries are performed only once.  You could execute it in an interval:

```
var checkPage = function(){
    if($(".slide:first").hasClass("active-slide")) {
        $(".prev").hide();
        $(".next").click (function () {
            $(".prev").show();
        });
    }
}

var intrvl = setInterval( checkPage, 300 );
```

This might work, but it could become really slow on big pages.

I'd rather attach the `checkPage()` function to the slide change event.

Comment: If you show us your page we could tell you where to attach the checkPage function so the page does not become slow on big pages or on old computers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `each()`, so that it executes every time slider:first occurs.

```
$(".slide:first-child").each(function(){
   // your function goes here    
});
```

EDIT: `:first` only targets the first instance of it on the page, so it will only fire one time anyway. You are probably looking for `:first-child`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm really a noob so I can't get it working using this code 

    $(".slide:first").each(function(){
     if($(this)).hasClass("active-slide") {
      $(".prev").hide();
   $(".next").click (function () {
    $(".prev").show();
   });
     }
 });`

Comment: first-child makes no difference, the prev is still showing up with the above code

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you mean. I don't think you can nest your code like that. What I would do, is to first hide `.prev` on `document.ready()` or when the slider is loaded, then check if the first slide has a class when you click `.next`, and hide/show as needed. I'm a bit short on time, but I'll try to make an example later.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll try to figure it out and if I do I'll mark your answer as correct but I'd still appreciate the example. Thanks a lot for your help!